# Is there a utility can set all unused bits to 1 in an SSD?

Tags: ssd

Is there a utility can set all unused bits to 1 in an SSD? If so, is using it an effective way to clear an SSD that does not support TRIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing outside the SSD itself can get to all the bits. There is a program called AS Cleaner (also called FreeSpaceCleaner) which you can have write FF (or 1s) to all empty sectors. This will cause a bunch of extra wear on them and does not produce nearly as good results as TRIM. You are better of relying on TRIM and built in garbage collection.

Download link: http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=12488&d=1257418520

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting page on [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2738/11) about it. Aparently, Intel released a tool that frees every single memory address in the SSD.

Comment: That page talks mostly about hdderase. I'm not looking for a full format of the SSD. Just initializing the unused bits to 1. Anyways I would recommend using hdparm command from a live CD instead of hdderase. The good thing is that its compatible with AHCI also.

Comment: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase.

Answer (score 0):

From [The SSD Relapse: Understanding and Choosing the Best SSD](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2829/13)

> The Indilinx Wiper Tool asks the OS
>   for all available LBAs (free space as
>   far as the OS is concerned), then
>   feeds the list to the SSD and tells
>   the drive to TRIM those LBAs -
>   prioritizing them for cleaning. It
>   shouldn’t touch valid data, the key
>   word being shouldn’t. Once cleaned,
>   with no existing data in those blocks,
>   performance goes back to its new
>   state.

Indilinx Wiper can be downloaded from the [OCZ support forum](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?57434-windows-with-Wiper-0525).